# How To change input type value in Laravel with if statement

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a web site. So, I am creating a registration form in this web site. There are drop down box which have Company name and text field which have address in this form. Now I want to show relevant address in same page when someone change the company name from the drop down box. I am very new to laravel.

How can I do this ??

Here is my Form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="signupForm">

{{ csrf_field() }}

<br><br>
Address : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="add" value="" id="username">

Company Name :
<select>
  <option value="Com 1">Com 1</option>
  <option value="Com 2">Com 2</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Comment: If you want to make another server request and do it by assigning a GET or POST variable.

But if you want to do it in the same page you might want to try an AJAX request

Comment: @NirojMaharjan - In the same page.. How can I do it ??

Comment: you can make a function that will show you the relevant address from the company name and then call it using AJAX and append it on your HTML.

Comment: @Amithash You create one controller where pass company id as parameter that controller return address value and that controller url call in ajax function that ajax function is called on onchange event on company select box.

Comment: @Amithash  If you don't know know ajax then you can check this link where one demo is that related dropdown change event of city and state dropdown.
http://www.expertphp.in/article/dependent-country-state-city-dropdown-using-jquery-ajax-in-laravel-5-example

Comment: @NirojMaharjan - I don't know Ajax.. Can u please implement it ??

Comment: @BhavinThummar - Thank U , I will check it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use jquery :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#company').val('Com 1');
   $('#company').trigger('change');
});

$(document).on('change','#company',function(){
  if($(this).val()=='Com 1'){
    $('#address').val("Address of Company 1");
  }else if($(this).val()=='Com 2'){
   $('#address').val("Address of Company 2");
  }
  else{
     $('#address').val("Default Address");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


Address : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="add" value="" id="address">

Company Name :
<select id="company" name="company">
  <option value="Com 1">Com 1</option>
  <option value="Com 2">Com 2</option>
</select>
```